# How do I extract a part of a string

Tags: string, go, split, glide-golang

I'm need to get a part a of a string, i.e.:
{
"token":"eyJ0eXjskdckjasdcaksdclkasdcsjnsc",
"expiresOnTimestamp":9234234
}

I've tried using split, splitafter. I need to get this token, just the token.

Comment: Your input is a JSON string, so treat it like that: use `encoding/json`. Do not try to split it. Or even better: since it's a JWT token, use a library that is specialized on that.

Comment: My bad, It's not an input it's an output, thats the response that I get for consuming a POST resquest, and I need to use only the token part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should parse it to `map[string]interface{}`:

```golang
jsonInput := []byte(`{ "token":"eyJ0eXjskdckjasdcaksdclkasdcsjnsc", "expiresOnTimestamp":9234234 }`)
jsonContent := make(map[string]interface{})

unmarshalErr := json.Unmarshal(jsonInput, &jsonContent)

if unmarshalErr != nil {
    panic(unmarshalErr)
}

token, _ := jsonContent["token"].(string)
```

Or create a dedicated `struct` for unmarshal:

```golang
type Token struct {
    Value              string `json:"token"`
    ExpiresOnTimestamp int    `json:"expiresOnTimestamp"`
}

jsonInput := []byte(`{ "token":"eyJ0eXjskdckjasdcaksdclkasdcsjnsc", "expiresOnTimestamp":9234234 }`)

var jsonContent Token

unmarshalErr := json.Unmarshal(jsonInput, &jsonContent)

if unmarshalErr != nil {
    panic(unmarshalErr)
}

token := jsonContent.Value
```

Comment: My bad I was unclear, the json token is an output not an input, does your suggestion apply the same?

Comment: Your JSON structure is *input* and `token` is the *output* in the application context.